# postscript code in psplot fails

Tags: pstricks, postscript

the following code snippet doesn't work as expected

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot}

\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}(10,10)

        \psplot{0}{10}{%
        5 x le { x } if 
    }

    \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Especially with regard to the PostScript-code

```
 5 x le { x } if
```

Simple postscripts without conditional executions or loops work fine. I have the sense that i might have to escape the curly braces, but escaping them with a slash doesn't work either.

Maybe someone of you experts can me help to solve my little problem!?

Let the wisdom be with you and best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to escape the braces, they are correctly passed to the DVI file. However, psplot expects the function to leave a value on the operand stack for each x. The expression

```
5 x le { x } if
```

doesn't create any value if the condition evaluates to false. Thus, you should replace it with some kind of `ifelse` construct instead, e.g. something like

```
5 x le {x} {0} ifelse
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast reply! You solved my problem...

Comment: I'm glad to hear you could solve your issue. If this answer was helpful to you, please think about accepting it.