# What is the correct RPN expression of a piecewise-defined function passed to \psplot?

Tags: pstricks, postscript, pst-plot

My objective is to pass a piecewise-defined function in RPN to `\psplot`. The complete code is given as follows. The function is `sin x` for `x<0` and `cos x` for other `x`.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-\psPi,-2)(\psPi,2)
    \psplot{Pi neg RadtoDeg}{Pi RadtoDeg}{x dup lt 0 {sin} {cos} ifelse}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The code above does not compile. So what is the correct syntax?

### Edit

When I tried (based on David Carlisle's answer)

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{plotpoints=3000}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-\psPi,-2)(\psPi,2)
    \psplot{Pi neg RadtoDeg}{Pi RadtoDeg}{x dup 0 lt {sin} {cos} ifelse}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I got an output (that is strange) as follows.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-\psPi,-2)(\psPi,2)
    \psplot[plotpoints=1000]{Pi neg}{Pi}{x RadtoDeg dup 0 lt { sin } {cos} ifelse}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

or in algebraic mode:

```
\begin{pspicture}(-\psPi,-2)(\psPi,2)
    \psplot[plotpoints=1000,algebraic]{Pi neg}{Pi}{IfTE(x<0,sin(x),cos(x))}
\end{pspicture}

IfTE(<expression>,<true>,<false>)
```

[image]

Comment: The source of confusion is: why must `RadtoDeg` be moved while you explained [here (click)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133847/19356) that appending `RadtoDeg` in both `{Pi Neg}` and `{Pi}` is necessary?

Comment: in a `polarplot` the x value must be in degrees. You need a `RadtoDeg`. But your function needs the x in radian, the reason why we have to convert it back. In `algebraic` mode the x values must be in radian.

Comment: I think the explanation (that `x` value is in degrees when using `polarplot=true` with postfix and `x` value is in radian when using `plotplot=true` with infix) is necessary in the `pst-plot` documentation as there is no such an explanation right now.

Comment: In the previous comment, `plotplot` is a typo, it should be `polarplot`. I am sorry for bothering you.

Comment: How to remove any vertical lines when plotting a piecewise function using `IfTE`?

Comment: then plot it piecewise ... One expression one plot

Comment: OK. Thanks. But it is a sad fact. :-)

Answer (score 4):

It's *R* PN :-)

```
    \psplot{Pi neg RadtoDeg}{Pi RadtoDeg}{x dup 0 lt {sin} {cos} ifelse}
```

`0 lt` not `lt 0`

Comment: @Marienplatz yes but I get similar if I just use x sin without any if block, it's a long time since I looked at ps-plot, is the synatx right?

Comment: @Marienplatz looks like you can, see this automatically linked question (in the list on the right) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53948/postscript-code-in-psplot-fails?rq=1  I think your scaling is out, as I say you similarly get a more or less straight line if you use just x sin